# Literal control not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, upload, uploadify

I am using a plugin called uploadify to show file upload progress to users. The uploadify script calls default.aspx (asynchronously). In the Page_Load method of the default.aspx I run validation checks on the other form data that was passed through it.

If a validation check fails I like to display an error message using a literal control and then exit. The problem is the literal control is not being updated with the validation error messages.

**Updated**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;


        if (context.Request.Files["Filedata"] != null)
        {
            if (context.Request["Name"] == null)
            {
                litValidationErrors.InnerHtml = "Please enter a name";

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'uploader': '/Plugins/Uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': '/default.aspx',
            'cancelImg': '/Plugins/Uploadify/images/cancel.png',
            'folder': '/FileUploads',
            'auto': false,

            'onComplete': function (event, ID, fileObj, response, data)
            {
                var uploadifyResponse = $("#<%= litValidationErrors.ClientID %>", $(response));

                if (uploadifyResponse.length > 0)
                {
                    $("#<%= litValidationErrors.ClientID %>").css("display", "inline").text(uploadifyResponse.text());
                }
            }

        });


        $('#MainContent_superSubmit').click(function ()
        {
            var jsonFormData = {
                'Name': $('#MainContent_txtName').val(),
                'Password': $('#MainContent_txtPassword').val()
            };

            $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings('scriptData', jsonFormData);
            $('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();
        });
    });
</script>


    <html>
    .....
    <asp:Button ID="superSubmit" runat="server" Text="Button"  />
 <span id="litValidationErrors" runat="server" style="display: none; color: #ff0000;"></span>
    </html>
```

Comment: The validation will only display if `Request.Files["Filedata"]` has a value and `Request.["Name"]` is null. Is this the logic you expect?

Comment: that's how i set it up. The code enters and sets the literal but it does.t stick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the litValidationErrors control from Literal to the span with runat="server", remove Visible="false" and hide it by setting style="display: none;". Also, add the onComplete event handler to the uploadify:

```
$(function () {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'uploader': '/Plugins/Uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': '/WebForm1.aspx',
            'expressInstall': '/Plugins/UploadifyexpressInstall.swf',
            'cancelImg': '/Plugins/Uploadify/images/cancel.png',
            'folder': '/App_Data/FileUploads',
            'auto': false,

            'onComplete': function (event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
                var uploadifyResponse = $("#<%= litValidationErrors.ClientID %>", $(response));

                if (uploadifyResponse.length > 0) {
                    $("#<%= litValidationErrors.ClientID %>").css("display", "inline").text(uploadifyResponse.text());
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I put in the changes but it still doesn't work. In Firefox nothing is displayed. In IE it flashes an error message every now and then, but it doesn't stay. I've updated my code in my original post with all your changes

Answer (score 0):

Add callback function to your script that will update the text of literal control

Comment: I googled for `uploadify` plugin but the I cannot get any documentation for it. Try the  @1stein answer.